# How do I get a Canon MF4150 printer working?

Tags: 11.10, printing, canon

As I am enjoying my new Ubuntu 11.10 OS (and impressed with it) I ran into some difficulties getting my Canon MF4150 printer to work. The printer seems to be installed properly (followed [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10745713&postcount=5)) however when I try to print something I get this error:

```
printer-state-message="/usr/lib/cups/filter/pstoufr2cpca failed"
```

I think I've come across the [solution](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/491205) but I don't know how to apply it to my version of Ubuntu.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1723101&page=2) in ubuntuforums.org.

The error you report can be managed.

I have solved it by compiling version 2.1 of the Canon driver, and installed it with `make install`.

Above the guy seems to have used another method linked to appArmor, but the printer prints nothing without error.

Comment: @user31208 You have never accepted this answer. Give votes and get votes. ;)

Comment: :) You're right. Done!